# how to consider only the white region on the image as contour

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I have a binary image, from which I need to consider only the white regions as contours but it also takes black region which is surrounded by white part as contour.
I don't want to use contour area, can we ignore the black regions while finding contours?
Here is the binary image and the orange color marked is also considered as contour, so do not want the black region surrounded with white to be considered as contour.

[image]                    [image]

Contour image is:

[image]

My contouring code:

```
//contouring
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(img, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f>centers(contours.size());
    vector<float>radius(contours.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours_poly[i]);
        minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i], centers[i], radius[i]);
    }
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 256), rng.uniform(0, 256), rng.uniform(0, 256));
        
        drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, (int)i, color);
}
```

Comment: You could do morphological closing on the image with appropriate kernel size to remove the holes https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html

Comment: I thought of that idea, but there are very huge holes and by applying closing operation it affects the further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets do not compose a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Therefore I could not run it for testing.

However - you might be able to achieve what you want by "playing" with the 2 last parameters of `cv::findContours`.

From opencv documentation of `cv::findContours`:

```
    mode    Contour retrieval mode, see [RetrievalModes][1]

    method  Contour approximation method, see [ContourApproximationModes][1]
```